# mysqldump: Got error: 0: when retrieving data from server

Tags: centos, mysql

The back up system I am running gives me this error

```
mysqldump: Got error: 0:  when retrieving data from server
```

I have been looking around and I failed to find another output with error code 0. I do not know if that even matters or not but I thought it would otherwise it would be same number as others. Thats why I made this topic.

Server is CentOs

MySQL version 5.5.33-31.1

What throws me off is that I have another box with same OS and MySQL version and it works fine.

[I have been looking at this site for reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html) but there is no code 0...

Any other information you need, please tell and I will put it here.

Comment: Are you replicating this box? Are you using statement based binlogs?

Comment: Yes replication. I am not sure what you mean by statement based binlongs. I know where the statement is if that's what you mean. I have added --ignore-table=mysql.event statement there. Rest of the statement is created mixed with php variables. Its the software's code thus I am not able to give you the full dump statement